# CSS box-shadow for solid button:focus without knowing background color?

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm working on [some button styles on codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/OjRmaM) and am using double box-shadow to produce this effect for use as a `:focus` state.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px currentColor, 0 0 0 5px var(--background);
```

[image: focused button with double box-shadow]

Is there a way to produce box-shadow like this without knowledge of the background color? Like to somehow inset the box-shadow? I'd like to produce this effect without needing to know the background color.

Comment: This is very unpolished and may not be what you're after but have you considered pseudo-elements? https://jsfiddle.net/nd840xzu/

Comment: So is pseudoelement with `currentColor` border OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the padding, then have an inset border by a certain amount. The inset border (really the outline) would be the white, while the outer orange would be part of the original background.

Comment: Can you please add demo to your answer?